# How to change Expo React native default port 19000

Tags: react-native, expo

I can change hostname with REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME env variable but can not find how to change the ports. I googled and [found .exprc](https://forums.expo.io/t/run-exp-start-on-another-port/6404/4) but it doesn't work for me.

**Edited:**

Sorry for the confusion but I would like to know how to change port with `expo`.

Answer (score 10):

In your `package.json` file change

```
"start": "expo start"
```

to

```
"start": "expo start --port 19001"
```

Comment: How to change the port for the web app, and the dev-tools?

Answer (score 2):

```
npx expo start --port=<YOUR_PORT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `RCT_METRO_PORT` environment variable (for Metro) and/or `WEB_PORT` (for Webpack), e.g.:

```
RCT_METRO_PORT=11111 WEB_PORT=22222 expo start
```

These seem to be undocumented, however, so use with care.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours with reading source codes but unable to find the config. I ended up updating `startDevServerAsync.js` script with the port I wanted. (I admit this is not good but I can't spend more time on just dealing with this)

```
$ which expo-cli
/home/shohey1226/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/expo-cli
$ cd  ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/start
$ sed -i 's/19000/8080/g' startDevServerAsync.js
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default port, you can create an .exprc file in your project root with

```
{
  "manifestPort": valid port number (e.g. 19002)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify this using the following CLI command:

```
npx react-native start --port=<YOUR_PORT>
```

as documented [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting#using-a-port-other-than-8081).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm using expo and haven't ejected yet.  How can I specify this port argument with expo?